# How to make GridView touch feedback like this?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

How I can make GridView touchfeedback like this?

[image]

I have tried this, but it still does not work, because I cant get any touch feedback.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/GridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/touch_listener"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="#000"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp" />



<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/yellow" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`android:drawSelectorOnTop`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:drawSelectorOnTop) in your gridview xml

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/GridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/touch_listener"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:background="#000"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
```

Comment: @petey ,can you pls help..
I have a grid view with image as a single item in grid
When I m clicking in space left around image ,I get touch feedback from gridview but no feedback on clicking on the image..
what can I do?
thanks.

Comment: @eRaisedToX  sounds like you should ask a new question for the community to answer

Comment: thank you for your valuable comment...I already would have done so If I could ..,, but since "questions" from my account are currently blocked I could only comment..
thanks!!